# check cron job has run script properly - proper way to log errors in batch processing

Tags: php, error-handling, cron, batch-processing

I have set up a cronjob to run a script daily.  This script pulls out a list of Ids from a database, loops through each to get more data from the database and geneates an XML file based on the data retrieved.

This seems to have run fine for the first few days, however, the list of Ids is getting bigger and today I have noticed that not all of the XML files have been generated.  It seems to be random IDs that have not run.  I have manually run the script to generate the XML for some of the missing IDs individually and they ran without any issues.

I am not sure how to locate the problem as the cron job is definately running, but not always generating all of the XML files.  Any ideas on how I can pin point this problem and quickly find out which files have not been run.

I thought perhaps add `timestart` and `timeend` fields to the database and enter these values at the start and end of each XML generator being run, this way I could see what had run and what hadn't, but wondered if there was a better way.

```
set_time_limit(0);

//connect to database
$db = new msSqlConnect('dbconnect');

$select = "SELECT id FROM ProductFeeds WHERE enabled = 'True' ";

$run = mssql_query($select);
while($row = mssql_fetch_array($run)){

    $arg = $row['id'];
    //echo $arg . '<br />';
    exec("php index.php \"$arg\"", $output);
    //print_r($output);

}
```

Comment: This is a bad idea, use (INNER) JOIN if all the record are relationship-able

Comment: bad idea?  please explain.  The databases are completley seperate.

Comment: Of course, you never indicate the data are located in different database. Please don't assume everyone know about your data structure.

Comment: Even the database are separated, there are still have way to make the above run efficiently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out the apache was timing out.  Therefore nothing to do with using a function or the exec() function.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to add some logging to the script. A simple

```
error_log("Passing ID:".$arg."\n",3,"log.txt");
```

Can give you some info on whether the ID is being passed. If you find that that is the case, you can introduce logging to index.php to further evaluate the problem.

Btw, can you explain why you are using exec() to run a php script? Why not excute a function in the loop. This could well be the source of the problem.

Because with exec I think the process will run in the background and the loop will continue, so you could really choke you server that way, maybe that's worth trying out as well. (I think this also depends on the way of outputting:

> Note: If a program is started with this function, in order for it to continue running in the background, the output of the program must be redirected to a file or another output stream. Failing to do so will cause PHP to hang until the execution of the program ends.

Maybe some other users can comment on this.

Comment: there is no reason for using exec().  So if I write it as a function instead, you think this will help?  If so, should I also record the successful and unsuccessful generated files?  thanks

Comment: That will certainly increase transparency of the script, and will decrease the chance of the script not executing because of a lack of resources for instance.

And yes, I would also log a successful file write, the more info you have the better. But there is a good change that just replacing the exec() with a function will fix the problem

Comment: Hi,I have changed my code to use a function as suggested but am still having the same issues. I have also added a query to update the database with a "lastGenerated" field to try and pinpoint at what stage the script is failing.  I have run the script three times this morning and it seems to stop randomly without any errors. :0/